# geom_rect() not plotting all data points

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am trying to create a copy number frequency plot using a combination of the geom_rect() and facet_grid() functions in R. In the end I would like something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5LGQ.png

I have a data frame consiting of the genomic location (chromosome, start, end) and copy number (cnv).

```
   chromosome    start      end cnv
1           3 66133610 66388116   1
2           4 74744759 74794523   1
3          17 41712331 41715969   1
4          17 41717742 41734644   1
5          17 41754604 41786931   1
6          17 41812680 41823213   7
7          17 41825057 41836260   3
8          15 20531856 20541800   5
9          17 41835685 41848384   3
10         15 20835372 20866314   4
```

When I run my code, the resulting plot doesn't contain all the data points from the data frame. Any help would be apprechiated.

Here is a simplified version of the code and data, that still results in the same problem:

```
library(ggplot2)

os.sub <- data.frame("chromosome"=c(3,"X",17,17, 17, 17, 17, 15, 17, 15), "start" = c(66133610, 74744759, 41712331, 41717742, 41754604, 41812680, 41825057, 20531856, 41835685, 20835372), "end" = c(66388116, 74794523, 41715969, 41734644, 41786931, 41823213, 41836260, 20541800,41848384, 20866314),"cnv"=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 3, 5, 3, 4))

ggplot(os.sub) + geom_rect(aes_string(xmin="start",xmax="end",ymin=0, ymax="cnv"))+ facet_grid(~chromosome)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/padD6.png

This is the output I get, with only two data points, instead of the expected 10.

Comment: Are some of your rectangles just too thin to show?  The range along the x axis is 54 million, yet your rectangles are only a few thousand wide. In other words, the rectangles are mostly much less than 1/1000 as wide as your plotting panels.  Even with a full screen plot on a large monitor, each of these panels is going to take up about 400 pixels, so each rectangle would be much less than one pixel wide. How this is drawn is device dependent; I use `ragg`, and can't replicate your problem. Perhaps try adding `color = 'gray'` to `geom_rect`; outlines are always drawn however thin the rectangle.

Comment: Incidentally, `aes_string` is deprecated. You can shorten and future-proof your code by changing to `aes(xmin = start, xmax = end  , ymin = 0, ymax = cnv)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we "free up" your x-scales we can see more. I think that, as Allan suggests, some of your widths are so small that they round to less than 1 pixel in the resulting plot.

```
ggplot(os.sub) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = start, xmax = end  , ymin = 0, ymax = cnv), alpha = 0.6) +
  facet_grid(~chromosome, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::comma_format()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

[image]